# Failing to pass Android Context using Autofac

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-service, autofac

I've decided to give Xarmarin a try, and I'd like to pass the android context.

I did a similar idea like this with Android and Roboguice back in the day. They had a provider factory, which would allow you to pass that item around to inject via properties.

I'd like to attempt this approach with IoC (Autofac ideally). I've followed this example: http://arteksoftware.com/ioc-containers-with-xamarin/

I'd like to add that I'm finding it difficult with services where I'd like to inject instances via the constructor.

Were you all able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've decided to give Xarmarin a try, and I'd like to pass the android context.

Directly **pass the android** context? No, there is no way to do that. The Interface is defined in PCL, but there is no proper container(type) in PCL to accept the context instance.

But you can define your own Interface and class to **leverage the Context instance**:

Example based on the demo of the blog you posted (leverage the context to read a `txt` file in Assets folder):

1. Add a txt file(abc.txt) in `Assets` folder and set it's `BuildAction` as `AndroidAssets`.
2. Define a new Interface in PCL:

   ```
   public interface IContextUtility
   {
       string GetAssetTxt(string str);
   }
   ```
3. Add a variable of IContextUtility in `MainViewModel.cs`:

   ```
   public class MainViewModel
   {
       private readonly IPlatform _platform;
       private readonly ISettings _settings;
       private readonly IContextUtility _contextUtility;

       public MainViewModel (IPlatform platform, ISettings settings,IContextUtility contextUtility)
       {
           _settings = settings;
           _platform = platform;
           _contextUtility = contextUtility;
       }

       public string Abc
       {
           get {
               return _contextUtility.GetAssetTxt("abc.txt");
           }
       }
     ...
   }
   ```
4. Add `IContextUtility` implementation in Android Project:

   ```
   public class MyContextUtility : IContextUtility
   {
       public string GetAssetTxt(string str)
       {
           string strToReturn = null;
           using (var stream = Application.Context.Assets.Open(str))
           {
               using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
               {
                   strToReturn=reader.ReadToEnd();
               }
           }
           return strToReturn;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Register a new instance in `App.cs`:

   ```
   [Application(Icon="@drawable/icon", Label="@string/app_name")]
   public class App : Application
   {
       public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

       public App(IntPtr h, JniHandleOwnership jho) : base(h, jho)
       {
       }

       public override void OnCreate()
       {
           var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
           builder.RegisterInstance(new MyContextUtility()).As<IContextUtility>();
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
6. Now, you can use it in your MainActivity:

   ```
   var text = viewModel.Abc;
   ```

Comment: @elvis-xia-msft: Thanks for the example. If I read this right, you're saying you can't do it. In the example above, just note that you build your code / class / implementation around the application [context].

Comment: Also.... so one of the things I'm trying to do is inject classes into a `Android.App.Service` and in this case it warns me that I need a default constructor